# Trying to get a UITextView to move content when keyboard is placed over top of itself

Tags: uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextview, swift4

I have a UITextView

```
    @IBOutlet weak var note: UITextView!
note.delegate = self
```

The text view is inside of a UIScrolLView

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
```

That I am trying to get to respond to this:

```
// move the scrollView when the keyboard is presented
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Keyboard), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Keyboard), name: Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
```

that when pressed called this function:

```
@objc func adjustForKeyboard(_ notification: Notification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let keyboardScreenEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
    let keyboardViewEndFrame = view.convert(keyboardScreenEndFrame, from: view.window)

    if notification.name == NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    } else {
        scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: keyboardViewEndFrame.height, right: 0)
    }
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = scrollView.contentInset
}
```

What I want to happen is when you tap on the UITextView, if the keyboard is going to hide the text view, the content is scrolled up, so that the TextView is always visible. This method works just fine for my UITextFields, but it's not working for the UITextView.

Followed this tutorial, and still not working for me. I'm not sure if he is using UITextView or UITextFields in the video, I think Fields.

[OW TO AUTO ADJUST UISCROLLVIEW WHEN KEYBOARD IS UP (SWIFT-4, XCODE-9)](http://NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,%20selector:%20#selector(Keyboard),%20name:%20Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide,%20object:%20nil)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,%20selector:%20#selector(Keyboard),%20name:%20Notification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame,%20object:%20nil))

[How to adjust a UIScrollView to fit the keyboard](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-adjust-a-uiscrollview-to-fit-the-keyboard)

Comment: What do you mean that your text view isn't responding to it? What is "it"? Clearly explain in detail (in your question, not in comments) what is actually happening and what you think should be happening but isn't.

Comment: Updated with more detail